# How can you tell if a Scala object is a function?

Tags: scala, reflection

Does Scala's reflection API provide a way to tell if a Scala object is a function? So far, the best I've come up with is:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def isFunction[T : TypeTag](x: T) =
  weakTypeOf[T] <:< weakTypeOf[Function0[_]] ||
  weakTypeOf[T] <:< weakTypeOf[Function1[_,_]] ||
  weakTypeOf[T] <:< weakTypeOf[Function2[_,_,_]] ||
  weakTypeOf[T] <:< weakTypeOf[Function3[_,_,_,_]] ||
  weakTypeOf[T] <:< weakTypeOf[Function4[_,_,_,_,_]] ||
  . . .
```

There has to be a better way.

Comment: They have no common supertype, so no, I don't think you can do it more succinctly. Why do you want to know??

Comment: I'm writing a little doodad to hook up functions to other functions, based on their ability to supply values of types needed by other functions (vaguely like _make_, but for values and functions rather than files and commands). It would be nice if I could just say, "Is that a function? OK, what argument types does it take, and what type does it return?"

Comment: Are you talking about the `andThen` construct in Scala?

Comment: I may end up calling `andThen`, but first I need to see which objects are functions and inspect their type signatures. Or, hmm, now that you mention it, maybe I could just call `andThen` and catch an exception if something is wrong… (Nah, that sounds like trouble.)

Comment: Use the type system, not reflection.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible, though I _would_ prefer to use the type system. I'm actually seeing if there's an easy way to do what I asked at [In lieu of trait arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600323/in-lieu-of-trait-arguments). I figure that if the type system won't let me put arguments on traits, maybe I can wangle it myself by composing functions at run-time. (Each trait I'm interested in just provides one function to get composed with others.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
10:21 ~/Projects/210x/sandbox (2.10.x)$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.5-20140407-165700-ec05aeb3d6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_40).

scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> definitions.FunctionClass.contains(typeOf[Function1[_, _]].typeSymbol)
res1: Boolean = true

10:22 ~/Projects/211x/sandbox (2.11.x)$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.1-20140509-211642-d079e769b9 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_40).

scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> definitions.FunctionClass.seq.contains(typeOf[Function1[_, _]].typeSymbol)
res0: Boolean = true
```

Comment: To my surprise, this works: `def isFunction[T : TypeTag](x: T): Boolean = definitions.FunctionClass.seq.contains(weakTypeOf[T].typeSymbol)` even though I'm passing it functions with specified type parameters. I've found the [2.10.4 documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/#scala.reflect.api.StandardDefinitions$DefinitionsApi) on the `DefinitionsApi`, which includes `FunctionClass`. Is there documentation for 2.11 that explains why the `.seq` is needed?

Comment: I just found the [2.11.1 documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/scala-reflect/index.html#scala.reflect.api.StandardDefinitions$DefinitionsApi). So does [`VarArityClassApi`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/scala-reflect/index.html#scala.reflect.api.StandardDefinitions$DefinitionsApi$VarArityClassApi) do some sort of magic to handle functions of any arity?

Answer (score 2):

The public API doesn't allow you to do it as far as I know, but there is always access to the internals:

```
scala> val st = scala.reflect.runtime.universe.asInstanceOf[scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse]
st: scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse = scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse@db03ddc

scala> st.definitions.isFunctionType(st.typeOf[Int])
res0: Boolean = false

scala> st.definitions.isFunctionType(st.typeOf[Int => Int])
res1: Boolean = true

scala> st.definitions.isFunctionType(st.typeOf[Function0[Int]])
res2: Boolean = true

scala> st.definitions.isFunctionType(st.typeOf[Function0[_]])
res3: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Verrry interesting. I just tried it out, and it works! Fortunately, I don't think I need the case where the type parameter is unspecified.

Comment: There is a public APi for that. `definitions` contain a number of important symbols that one can check against.

Comment: Btw the crash occurs only if you cast to scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable, because runtime reflection can't pick the right classloader (the one that contains $iw) and speculatively uses the one that loaded scala-library.jar.

Comment: The auto-classloader magic happens only if the prefix of the typeOf call is a subtype of scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse, so if you cast to `scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse` (which inherits from both api.JavaUniverse and internal.SymbolTable), then you should be fine.